# rostopic publish constant value

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS messages allow the definition of constants (e.g. for emulating enum types). Is there a way to publish these named values in "rostopic pub"?

For example, I have a defined message type Emotion.msg:

```
uint32 emotion
float64 intensity
uint32 NEUTRAL=0
uint32 HAPPY=1
uint32 SAD=2
```

The idea is that the emotion value is set to one of the constants, and I don't really want to remember what the constants are as values.

The following works as expected, but is not ideal:

```
rostopic pub  --once /set_emotion my_msgs/Emotion  1 0.5
```

Rather, I want to publish something like

```
rostopic pub  --once /set_emotion my_msgs/Emotion  HAPPY 0.5
```

or at least

```
rostopic pub  --once /set_emotion my_msgs/Emotion my_msgs/Emotion/HAPPY 0.5
```

Neither of these seem to work, since the constants get interpreted as strings. Is there a way to specify named constants in the rostopic utility?
Neither of these seems to work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12179/rostopic-publish-constant-value/) by [Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/237/nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2011-12-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since rostopic pub uses YAML for parsing command line arguments, I'm not sure it supports constants (there's nothing about constants on this page, for example: [ROS/YAMLCommandLine](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/YAMLCommandLine)). What you could use, however, is rosh, which uses an interactive Python specification. See here: [rosh/Overview/Topics#rostopic_pub](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosh/Overview/Topics#rostopic_pub).

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2011-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1